# NodeJs HTML-PDF Library <pre> tag cutting PDF at right page

Tags: css, node.js, razor, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I'm having an issue with a node libray (html-pdf). I'm trying to render html to pdf, but the PDF page is not showing correctly.

When I try to insert a  tag, the workflow is cutting the right side of the page, and it doesn't show the entire text. How can I solve it?

I've tried applying diferent styles to the  tag but none of them works... Here is a screenshot about my problem:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found a solution for my case.
Adding this code to my CSS worked.

```
pre {
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            /* Since CSS 2.1 */
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
            /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
            white-space: -pre-wrap;
            /* Opera 4-6 */
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
            /* Opera 7 */
            word-wrap: break-word;
            /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
        }
```